# How do I split a text into different values?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I want to split the inputted data then check each line so if it's a number it gets pushed into the score Array and if not then it gets pushed into the name Array. I'm new and I have no idea what I'm doing. so far I have this :

```
var lines:Array = String(event.target.data).split(":");

var linesNum:int = lines.length;
for(var i:int = 0 ; i < linesNum; i++){
  trace('line ' + i + ': ' + lines[i]);

var scores:Array = []; 

for (var i:int; i < lines.length; i++) {
  scores.push(lines[i]);
}
classone_import.text = (scores.sort());
```

Comment: Show us the input data (an example).

Comment: *Test B:10
*Test A:0
*Test C:7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use regular expressions.

```
var str:String = "*Test B:10 *Test A:0 *Test C:7";

var wordsRe:RegExp = /\w+ \w+/g; // word + space + word
var valuesRe:RegExp = /\d+/g; // only digits

var names:Array = str.match(wordsRe);
var scores:Array = str.match(valuesRe);

trace(names);//Test B, Test A, Test C
trace(scores);//10, 0, 7
```

Comment: Not that your solution would be bad but are you seriously suggesting to use RegExp to a beginner? (smthg to think about) Plus imagine this: var str:String = "*Test 1:10 *Test 2:0 *Test 3:7";  ;)

Comment: Thank you I managed to get help  with the previous solution but as this one is simpler it made it easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
var s:String = "*Test B:10 *Test A:0 *Test C:7";
var divider:String = "*"; //the divider is "*" - taken from your example
var arr:Array = s.split(divider); //split the string by the specified divider

var scores:Array = [];
var names:Array = [];

for(var i:int=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] == "") continue; //I am not sure whether this will occur but as your string begins with *, the first item may be "" -> so skip that
    var item:Array = arr[i].split(":"); //split the string to 'name', 'score'
    names.push(item[0]);
    scores.push(parseFloat(item[1])); //parse the number from string; you could use parseInt if all the numbers are integers for sure
}
```

Then you can sort it or whatever you intend to do with it.